# Exact position of element in array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using below code to search string in array and print corresponding response code. But below code always print **Approved1** in all cases (i.e. 000,00,0)

```
$resp_desc=["Approved1","Approved","Fail"];
$resp_table=["000","00","0"];
$description=array_search("0",array_keys($resp_table));
$desc1=$resp_desc[$description];
echo $desc1;
```

Please guide in above matter.

Comment: why are you searching in the array_keys and not the values?

Comment: It's not totally clear, but you also probably want to pass the third parameter as `true` to `array_search`. Otherwise all those values will be considered equal, since it will do a loose comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are searching in the array keys not the values of the array, set restrict to true in the array_search so you have only one result

```
$description=array_search("0",$resp_table,true);
```

Comment: Note that the third argument `exact` also is important here, as `array_search("0", $resp_table);` also returns `0`.